# HBase performance tuning factors

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am running Hbase 0.94.0. I've inserted 100000 1Lakh records. My write performance without tuning any performance factors is 60 secs and to read a single record it is 5ms. How to improve my performance.

I've searched the internet and i'm not getting any idea of how to improve my hbase performance.

Is there any specific site ?

Comment: That's too general - what is your key? what are your read access patterns ?

Comment: @Amon Rotem-Gal-Oz Can you please read my next post? I've clearly explained everything with the source code. Help me with answers.

Answer (score 3):

Apache provided very good performance tuning doc. Please refer below link for database side performance tuning.

[Hbase Performance tuning](http://hbase.apache.org/book/perf.writing.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you use HDD drive, changing to SSD will increase performance completely!